# wifi problem with HP spectre x2

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

I have a issues with my wifi, i have **Hp spectre 13 x2**, wifi card Intel Wireless-AC 7260 and its works as long as i do not reboot laptop.
Now when wifi is working:

```
rfkill list
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
10: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
11: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when i look on wmi so can see this

```
dmesg | grep wmi
[    2.571021] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   10.505719] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras
[   89.246158] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop WMI Extras unloaded
```

And after i reboot laptop so have i `Acer-Wireless LAN` in rfkill list so i must run this command: `rmmod -f acer-wmi` and `echo "blacklist acer.wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf` and wait for a few minutes/hours

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"......."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point:......as:32   
          Bit Rate=26 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:149   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

This will disable the `acer_wmi` module that blocks Wi-Fi.

Your previous command was wrong. You need to remove `acer-wmi.conf` by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf
```